# Need some help with the ALT + Shift + S function

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I'm trying to use the <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> function to turn a selection of mesh into a circle so that I can cut a circular hole in an object. The right side of the image is what it's supposed to look like, and the one on the left is what I get with the object I'm trying to model, ignoring the clipping, it comes out elongated. I think it's because the object is rectangular but I don't know to work around that. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I think it`s best if you scale the faces and move them on the z-axis instead of using a tool that works best for 3D objects

Comment: if it doesn't work you can still use LoopTools > Circle

Comment: As moonboots said enable the ' loop tools ' addon in the preferences, select the faces you want to turn into a circle, right-click and you can find the 'loop tools', hover over it and press 'circle'.

Comment: Managed to get it to work with Loop tools. Thanks a ton for the help guys!

Comment: your welcome hammoud :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem it looks like this is that you've scaled your model in *Object Mode* instead of *Edit Mode*, which means the scale is not uniform on all axes. In this case, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> stretches the circle according to the stretched scale.

To make it work, apply the scale in *Object Mode* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

By the way: I'm not sure how you managed to do it with the *Loop Tools*, because (at least in my Blender) you'll get the same result no matter which method you use, as long as the scale is not applied.

Comment: I Applied the scales and now it works perfectly. the loop tools worked for me probably because i used them on a mesh scaled with edit mode. now my problems is 100% solved, thanks for your help!